# Show multiple row values in a single column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:
(products(id, etc, etc, etc) and product_gallery(id, product_id, image, etc))
A single product can have more than 1 picture.
when I run a query to retrieve every product with its pictures returns a row for each picture although its the same product with the same id. 
Is there a way to change the query to show all the product_gallery.image values for the same product.id in the same column in a single row?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at using `group_concat`...

Comment: I'm trying to get that query to an exactly format to export it as csv and need the first picture as main picture and any other in a column named product_gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to `SELECT ..., GROUP_CONCAT( product_gallery.image ) ...` and get a comma-separated list of all the images for that product. However, that's typically a bad idea.

Instead, break the logic up into two separate queries. First, select all the products. Then, for each product, select the pictures. Yes, that generates more queries, but it guarantees you're selecting the data you want when you want it.